# ui-sref is not working inside apk

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ui-sref

I create an apk using with yeoman angularjs-cordova

I put here only specific require Folder Structure 
Module

- Core -> Views -> home.html
- Customer

  -> Config -> route.js

  -> Views -> dashboard.html

In home.html a link  `<a ui-sref="dashboard">User Dashboard</a>` is there.

My route.js of Customer module is

```
'use strict';

//Setting up route
angular.module('customer').config(['$stateProvider',
    function($stateProvider) {
        // Customer state routing
        $stateProvider.
        state('dashboard', {
            url: '/dashboard',
            views: {
                '@':{
                    templateUrl: 'app/modules/customer/views/dashboard.html',
                    controller: 'CustomerController'
                },
                'left@dashboard':{
                    templateUrl: 'app/modules/customer/common/left.html',
                    controller: 'CommonController'
                },
                'header@dashboard':{
                    templateUrl: 'app/modules/customer/common/header.html',
                    controller: 'CommonController'
                },
            },
        })
 }
]);
```

ui-sref is working properly in web browser but in Android device ui-sref is not working